# how to increase height of cell for the UIImagePickerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hi i have ImagePickerViewController i Need to increase the height of the cell its look's like the tableview and i need to increase that cell height of the imagePickerviewController.

```
I hope every one can understand my question.

i am attaching the picture
```

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    UIImagePickerController *albumPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [albumPicker setDelegate:self];
    [albumPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [albumPicker setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(300, 700)];

    [self.window addSubview:albumPicker.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photos"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                  target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    [bar setHidden:NO];
    ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
    ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @"Photos";
    ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

For the given picture which is an UIImagePicker And i need to increase its cell height.

I try my luck.  can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously UITableView. Height of all cells could be set over rowHeight property of UITableView or individually for each cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewDelegate. Have a look in your sources to understand where UITableView is set.

Comment: There is no UITableView I have writen in my code I have just calling UIImagePickerViewController That's automatically showing imagepicker in tableview cells

Answer (score 0):

To increase the height of the TableView cell implement the below method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height;
    height = 44;
    return height;

}
```

Comment: thanks it will increase the height of TableView cell.  But I need to increase the height of UIImagePickerViewController How do i controll the height of the ImagePicker.  ????

Comment: for Image that is shown on the Cell try to setFrame with the height and width you want...